# How to draw horizontal line in fo-block?

Tags: xsl-fo

i need to implement next layout:

[image]

here's my code:

```
<fo:block text-align="center">United Nations Organisation</fo:block>                
<fo:block border-top-style="solid" text-align="center">(organisation)</fo:block>        
<fo:block border-top-style="solid" text-align="center">(department)</fo:block>
```

but in fact the 2nd horizontal line is not drawn.
how can i achieve that? what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which FO processor? I test with RenderX and FOP and both show two horizontal lines as expected.

Comment: Works with me as well. What did you view the PDF with and and what distance? Might be that your Adobe Reader "Enhanced thin lines" (menu option) which leads to certain lines disappearing at a certain zoom level.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`fo:leader`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_leader)

```
<fo:block text-align="center">United Nations Organisation </fo:block>   
<fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="100%" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness="2pt"/>             
<fo:block text-align="center" font-size="8pt" margin-top="1mm">(organisation)</fo:block>        
<fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="100%" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness="2pt"/>
<fo:block text-align="center" font-size="8pt" margin-top="1mm">(department)</fo:block>
```

Comment: In my case, I had to encapsulate the <fo:leader> tags inside the <fo:block>s to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the `border-bottom-width` and the `border-bottom-style`.

I changed the `margin-top` to match your example.

```html
<fo:block 
  border-bottom-width="2pt" 
  border-bottom-style="solid" 
  border-bottom-color="black" 
  font-weight="bold" 
  text-align="center">
    United Nations Organisation 
</fo:block>            
<fo:block text-align="center" font-size="8pt" margin-top="1mm">
  (organisation)
</fo:block>        
<fo:block border-bottom-width="2pt" border-bottom-style="solid"margin-top="7mm">
</fo:block>
<fo:block text-align="center" font-size="8pt" margin-top="1mm">
  (department)
</fo:block>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the solution to adopt if your horizontal line lies in a header/footer.  Otherwise, you would get a `"fo:leader" is not a valid child of "fo:static-content"!` error.